# How to remove the word 'Chapter from toc in latex doc while retaining it on chapter pages?

Tags: table-of-contents

I am using document class Nemilov1 suggested by CRC Press, in a document. The problem I am facing is that I want to give the word 'Chapter' on the title pages e.g. Chapter 1; Chapter 2; etc. BUT I do not want the word appear in the table of contents. That should show only as:

```
1. Challenges Ahead........................1
   [followed by sections 1.1, 1.2, etc.] [ and then ]
2. Achievements so Far ....................21
```

While I have tried to find a solution to this problem by searching for my problem on Google, but to my utter dismay the solutions proposed are invariably the opposite.
I say, for eg.: How to remove the word 'Chapter' from the toc in a latex doc.

Solutions shown are:
eg. Hot to remove the word chapter from the chapter while retaining it in the toc

and so on.

Any help?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`. -- In particular, I don't know if the Nemilov1 class is anywhere public. It didn't show up on a quick Google search, at least.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you wanted:

```
\documentclass[12pt, oneside]{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter[Challenges Ahead]{Chapter 1: Challenges Ahead}
% The title within curly braces will print on chapter page while 
% the title within brackets will appear in the table of contents
% and in header

% This can be done with parts, chapters, sections, subsections etc.

\chapter[Achievements so Far]{Chapter 2: Achievements so Far}

\end{document}
```